# Gun lost in Battlefield 3

Tags: battlefield-3

I am playing the multiplayer online on the Xbox. I unlocked a sniper rifle I really like, then when I went back to play the next round the gun I unlocked was gone. I did not pick the gun up off of anybody. I unlocked it when I was promoted.

Where did my gun go and how can I get it for each round I play? Will it keep disappearing for one game then show up again for the next?

Comment: Hi @Vanessa, welcome to Arqade!  You can see BlueRaja has linked a very similar question, that has already been asked.  We try to close exact duplicate questions, in order to keep the site clean and help folks find the best answers (by putting them all in one place).  Check out that question, and if it isn't what you meant here, please edit you're question to explain the differences.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening anymore. This was patched about 9 months ago. I don't think this is a duplicate